# How to put a link to an image already linked in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a similar Apple site to learn HTML & CSS, and I stopped when I couldn't figure out how to put a link on an image that already has a link itself, I will post here the "code" hoping someone can help me...

```html
<a href="https://apple.com/iphone-14">
  <div class="hero" style="background-image: url(Images/iPhone_14-HERO-SMALL.jpg); margin-top: -15mm">
    <header class="titleText">
      <div style="color: #1D1D1E; font-family: SF-Pro-Bold;">iPhone 14</div>
      <div style="color: #1D1D1E; font-size: 7.5mm;">Big and bigger.</div>
      <span style="color: black"><a href ="https://apple.com/iphone-14">Learn more ></a></span>
      <!-- This is the part that deletes the whole link image -->
    </header>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You have an extra `>` between **Learn More** and **`</a>`**. Is this misspelled here or it is in your code?

Comment: It's supposed to be as a part of the text, I edited that with &gt; otherwise

Comment: You cannot put a link `<a>` within another `<a>`. You need to change your markup to create separate elements outside of each other. The closing `</a>` tag on the `learn more` will always close the opening `<a>`

Comment: As I thought so... Thank you everyone for the help anyway and also sorry for wasting your time. Bye!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should attend that using a block-level element like `div` or the worse than that `header` element! in an inline-level element like `a` is not html5 standard then according to your DOM you are wrapping a link inside another one! So it is better to write your DOM something like example below:

```html
<a class = "hero" style = "background-image: url(Images/iPhone_14-HERO-SMALL.jpg); margin-top: -15mm">
   <span style = "color: #1D1D1E; font-family: SF-Pro-Bold;">iPhone 14</span>
   <span style = "color: #1D1D1E; font-size: 7.5mm;">Big and bigger.</span>
<a href ="https://apple.com/iphone-14" style = "color: black; position: relative; z-index: 2">Learn more ></a>
</a>
```

and if you wanna have a block level element so style display: block to your inner spans

Comment: I tried the part you provided but it's not working as expected... The thing I want to do is that the background image has a link and a link text on it, I don't know if I explained well the idea...
Also tried putting the image inside the <a> tag but it's not working as expected... The image gets very small, not as if I use the <div> tag or it does not show neither

Comment: The answer updated according to your dependency; As I change the answer you can add a position relative and topper z-index to your inner ``` a ``` to be on top of the elements to can be clickable

Comment: The <a> tag works, it's the image link which is not working.

Comment: So your url is incorrect it may be ``` ./Images/iPhone_14-HERO-SMALL.jpg ```

Comment: Nope, the URL is correct...

Comment: add display inline-block or block to your a element

Comment: If I put display: inline-block to the HERO class, the whole block gets instantly small and moves to the left-top part of the Page

Comment: Could you add your code in https://codepen.io/ to be more clearly to help

Comment: Sure wait a moment

Comment: and if you wanna to got the whole line so you can add display: block to your element all your issues could be solve with css styles

Comment: The link to the project -> https://codepen.io/fa-ce-dev/pen/MWGPMaj
Sorry if I don't know much on this but I started HTML/CSS last week so I don't have much experience...

Comment: your problem is showing <a href = "index.html" style = "font-size: 4.5mm;" class = "menuItems"><img src = "Images/logo2" width = "20px" height = "20px" alt = ""></a> image?

Comment: Nope, that's the apple icon on the NavBar, that's just working well... The problem is at line 21 to 34

Comment: I changed a little your DOM according to html standards and as you can see the red background assigned to the div so your image address that passed to the background-image is incorrect try to change the url

Comment: I copied the image path from the PC to the code, I mean, how can it be incorrect I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.apple.com/iphone-14/"><img src="image-link-here" alt=""></a>
```